# Pushing Woocommerce orders to Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-apps-script, google-sheets, woocommerce

I have setup a woocommerce website, used for delivery of meals from different restaurants in my area.  I have tried to setup an automatic transfer of the order data from the json file straight to a Google sheet our drivers use, but I have found myself encountering errors in Google Script everytime woo's webhook fires, and not being able to detect the issue.

Here is my google script code

```
//this is a function that fires when the webapp receives a GET request
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("request received");
}

//this is a function that fires when the webapp receives a POST request
function doPost(e) {
  var myData = JSON.parse([e.postData.contents]);
  var order_number = myData.number;
  var order_address = myData.billing.address_1;
  var item = ""
  var url = "https://fivestars-delivery.com/mon-compte//driver-dashboard/?orderid=" + order_number;

  for (var i = 0; i < myData.line_items.length(); ++i) {
    item += myData.line_items[i].product_id + "\n"
    total += parseInt(myData.line_items[i].total)
  }

  var fees = ""
  // var feesTotal = 0

  for (var i = 0; i < myData.fee_lines.length(); ++i) {
    // convertir en entier
    // feesTotal += parseInt(myData.fee_lines[i].total)
    fees += myData.fee_lines[i].amount + " " + myData.fee_lines[i].name + " - " + myData.fee_lines[i].total + "\n"
  }

  var discount = myData.discount_total
  // nom client
  var nomClient = myData.first_name + " " + myData.last_name
  var order_total = myData.total;
  var payment_method = myData.payment_method_title;
  var phone = myData.billing.phone

  var note = myData.billing.address_2 + "\n" + myData.customer_note

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  sheet.appendRow([order_number, " ", " ", " ",order_address, " ", "Attente d'envoi",url, order_total, payment_method, nomClient, phone, note, item + fees + discount, ]);
}
```

-I set up a **WooCommerce API** and **webhook** using the api's secret key

-Entered my *web application's URL* as *delivery URL* in the webhook

I cannot find out what is wrong and none of the situations I found online have found no help so far.

Comment: It seems like you might be able to use urlFetchApp to generate the url for the doget with sample post data.  And that way you could run it more often and it would under your control.  Then it would be like debugging anything else.

Comment: Can you provide more details about `errors in Google Script everytime woo's webhook fires`? What kind of errors are you encountering? And where are you encountering them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `total` is never created, but it is used within the `for` loop.